# Extracting first rows of .csv files into a single new .csv file

Tags: debian, csv

I have over 1000 .csv files in a folder on Debian Squeeze. I am trying to create a new .csv file containing ONLY the first rows of each of these 1000 .csv files.

I tried:

```
read -r firstline < sourcefile_1.csv > headers.csv
```

But that only created a blank file. (And even if it did work, I would have copied only the first row of just one file.)

How do I write a command that copies the first rows of all 1000 files in the folder and add it to the new .csv file?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`head -q -n 1 *.csv > output.csv`
`-q` supresses the headers that normally get printed, `-n 1` prints only the first line

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the CSV files all contain headers and may contain fields with embedded newlines, we can't just run `head` on each file (as this may truncate records, and since this would also include the header from each file).

Instead of `head`, using a CSV-aware tool, such as [Miller](https://miller.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) (`mlr`), would be a better option:

```bash
mlr --csv put -q 'FNR == 1 { emit $* }' *.csv
```

This outputs the first data record of each file matching the `*.csv` filename globbing pattern.

Example:

```bash
$ cat file1
a,b
1,2
3,4
$ cat file2
a,b
5,6
7,8
$ cat file3
a,b
field one,"last
field
here"
```

```bash
$ mlr --csv put -q 'FNR == 1 { emit $* }' file[123]
a,b
1,2
5,6
field one,"last
field
here"
```

If the CSV files are header-less, use `mlr` with its `-N` option.